# gmail send api failed with error code 400 in meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, gmail-api

I am trying to send mail using gmail api in my meteor application, which returning below error,

```
Error in calendar insert: Error: failed [400] {  "error": {   "errors": [    {        "domain": "global",     "reason": "invalidArgument",     "message": "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required"    }   ],   "code": 400,   "message": "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required"  } }
```

I have tried the below,

```
"sendGmail": function(str) {
    this.unblock();
        var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send";

        var encodedMail = new Buffer(str).toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

        try {
        Meteor.http.post(url, {
            'headers' : { 
                'Authorization': "Bearer " + Meteor.user().services.google.accessToken,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            },
            'body': JSON.stringify({
                "raw": encodedMail
            })
          });
        } catch(e){
            console.log("Error in calendar insert: " + e);
        } finally {
          return true;  
        }
}
```

passing the below string value as argument:

```
    var str = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" +
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\n" +
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n" +
        "to: arunmail2u@gmail.com\n" +
        "from: arunsugan08@gmail.com\n" +
        "subject: Meteor test mail\n\n" +

    "Hi, this is test mail from meteor application";

     Meteor.call('sendGmail', str);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A body string is given as `content`, not `body`. [Check the documentation](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-http-package/#tmc-standard-http-requests-in-meteor).

> **content** - Takes a plain String and sets it on the HTTP request body.

Comment: Thank you! data doesn't, however 'content' is working fine :-)

Comment: @Arun Ah, you are right :) `content` is a pure string, and `data` takes an object which will be made into a string by the library. I updated the answer.